# QML how to use mouse hover together with styleData.selected

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to build a simple delegate for rows in TableView.
I want it to show a border in case hovered with mouse and leave a border in cases it's selected. See code below:

```
  Component
  {
    id: rowDelegate
    Item
    {
      height: 40

      Rectangle
      {
        id: rowRectSel
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "grey"
        radius: 2
        opacity: 0.4
        border.width: 3;
        visible: styleData.selected
      }

      Rectangle
      {
        id: rowRect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "grey"
        radius: 2
        opacity: 0.4
        border.width: 1;
        visible: !styleData.selected
      }

      MouseArea
      {
        id: rowMouseA
        hoverEnabled: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        preventStealing: false
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        enabled: !styleData.selected
      }

      states:
      [
        State
        {
          name: "hover"
          when: rowMouseA.containsMouse
          PropertyChanges { target: rowRect; border.width: 2; }
        }
      ]
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't show *rowRectSel* when MouseArea (*rowMouseA*) is there - somehow blocks the row to change *styleData.selected* property.
If I remove the MouseArea or set *enabled* property to false the *rowRectSel* is visible when selected.

Comment: Where ist styleData defined?

Comment: Under this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#itemDelegate-prop) it's called as 'special property'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TableView - How to get hovered row without loosing styleData.selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684357/tableview-how-to-get-hovered-row-without-loosing-styledata-selected)