# TableView - How to get hovered row without loosing styleData.selected

Tags: qt, qml, tableview

I need to highlight the hovered row in a `TableView`.
By default there is no hovering effect.
I can use a `MouseArea` inside `rowDelegate` to achieve this.
But this will disable selection mechanism in `TableView`.

Means `styleData.selected` will not work anymore. 
Which means I have to program each and every line of code for the selection mechanism including extended selection.

How to solve this issue? I just need a little property such as `styleData.hovered` like in `handle` component of `ScrollViewStyle`

The question is already asked 3 years & 2 months ago. Unanswered unfortunately.

[QML how to use mouse hover together with styleData.selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677464/qml-how-to-use-mouse-hover-together-with-styledata-selected)

**UPDATE**

```
    rowDelegate: Rectangle {
            height: 30

            property color selectedColor: styleData.hasActiveFocus ? "gray" : "lightgray"
            color: styleData.selected ? selectedColor : mouse_area.hovered?"black":backgroundColor

            MouseArea{
                id:mouse_area
                property bool hovered:false
                propagateComposedEvents : false

                hoverEnabled: true
                anchors.fill: parent

                onEntered: {
                    hovered=true
                }

                onExited: {
                    hovered=false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried setting MouseArea.propagateComposedEvents to 0.  But it is still not working.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Btw if you work with `QtQuick.Controls 1.4` you have to set selection manually, if you provide custom row delegate.

Comment: I am using ```QtQuick.Controls 1.4``` ```TableView``` ```QtQuick 2.13``` ```TableView``` is not that useful I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding:

```
MouseArea {
    // ...
    onPressed: mouse.accepted = false
}
```

will propagate the mouse signal to the `TableView` and keep its selection behavior.

Comment: Thanks. It works well. Everyone who wants to customize TableView should know this

Comment: This will introduce another issue. Now I am no longer able to get ```clicked``` and ```doubleclicked``` events for ```rowDelegate```.  Fortunately I found an answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849848/how-do-i-correctly-handle-mouse-events-in-a-qml-tableview-with-overlapping-mouse